# create a connection to a BluetoothLE device using Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

A few days ago, I downloaded the Bluetooth Smart Scanner software on Google Play Store. After installed it on my Samsung Galaxy S3 phone, I could scan my Bluetooth LE device successfully.

Even though I had tried all ways to scan my bluetooth LE device, there was nothing displayed on my computer. So I decompiled this software, there was a `startLeDiscovery()` method in the package `android.bluetooth`. But what confused me was that this method didn't exist in my `android.jar` of android sdk 15.

At last, I replaced the `BlutoothAdapter.class` file and `BluetoothDevice.class` file of `android.jar` with them of Bluetooth Smart Scanner software, so that I could successfully call the `startLeDiscovery()` method in Eclipse. The source code as shown below.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    IntentFilter intent = new IntentFilter();
    intent.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    intent.addAction(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_UUID);
    intent.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_GATT_PRIMARY_UUID);

    registerReceiver(searchDevices, intent);
    //bluetooth.discovery();      
    bluetooth.startLeDiscovery();

  }  
    private BroadcastReceiver searchDevices = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        BluetoothDevice device = null;

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);   
            String msg = device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress();
            Log.i("hella",msg);
            bluetooth.cancelDiscovery();
            connectDevice(device);
        }
    }       
};`
```

It turned out that I successfully scanned my bluetooth LE device on Galaxy s3 phone as what I thought. Otherwise, I found there also has a `com.samsung.bluetoothle` package. As the same way, I added it in my `android.jar`. But I couldn't connect to my LE device using those methods in that package.

I kindly request help from you to solve this problem that has plaguing us for a long time. In order to facilitate the development, I will contribute my `android.jar` on website. You'll see the `startLeDiscovery()` method and other methods in `android.bluetooth` directory. Of course, there also a  `com.samsung.bluetoothle` package in `android` directory.

You can download the `android.jar` package [here](http://download.csdn.net/detail/yuan8222/4709467) ( [Mirror](http://ul.to/e0wn7fv9) ) .

Answer (score 0):

The `android.jar` file is considered to be classes that are ALREADY available on your Android device: if I recall correctly those classes are not included in the APK that is generated for your app, so adding the `com.samsung.bluetoothle` classes to `android.jar` will not make them get added to your app.

Instead of decompiling and adding it to the `android.jar` file, why not just download the entire SDK from Samsung's website (http://developer.samsung.com/ble) and just use that in the recommended fashion?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a uses-library tag in your AndroidManifest.xml to tell the app to use the Galaxy S3 bluetooth library. Samsung never publicly released a library for developers so you do have to make your own jar file to compile against, but don't include the jar in the packaging of your apk.

```
<uses-library android:name="com.samsung.bluetoothle.BluetoothLEClientProfile" android:required="false" />
```

To access the methods of BluetoothAdapter and BluetoothDevice you are best off using reflection to get references to the methods you need and call them that way.