# How to get android.jar include startLeDiscovery() Method in BluetoothAdapter class

Tags: bluetooth

I saw a page,
[create a connection to a BluetoothLE device using Samsung Galaxy S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169987/create-a-connection-to-a-bluetoothle-device-using-galaxy-s3)
But I can't get jar file.
Or Are there any solution to use bluetooth le in android?

Answer (score 0):

You could give this [framework](https://github.com/android-btle/framework) a try.

Also, there are code samples on [this Android issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33371) (see comments [208](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33371#c208)/[209](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33371#c209)), but I don't think any of them offer a complete end to end working solution.

You could also attempt to contact Samsung directly and inquire if they have an SDK available (They might, but if they do, it's private at this time).